# Spring JPA: How should I create/use a look up table?

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

So I have 2 different entities:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class PickupOrderEvent(
        @Id
        override val id: UUID,

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        override val eventType: EventType,


        // other fields...
)

@Entity
data class DeliveryOrderEvent(
        @Id
        override val id: UUID,

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(nullable = false)
        override val eventType: EventType,


        // other fields... different than PickupOrderEvent
)
```

Both of these inherit from a parent class `OrderEvent`, but they have other (different) fields.

What I ultimately want to do, is to receive an `OrderEvent id`, and get that event from its respective table. However, I don't want to look at both tables (and later, even more tables) to figure out what the type is.

I imagined the right answer here, is to create a "lookup table" which looks something like this:

```kotlin
Events(
   val eventId: UUID, // FK to the other tables PK
   val eventType: EventType
)
```

So I would do the following:

1- Look at this table, and figure out what the `eventType` is for this Order.

2- Look at the respective tables (depending on the eventType above) and get the event

How can/should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a look up table.

This looks more like a case for the ["JOINED" inheritance mapping strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#joined-table).